# Break Before Make Implementation

Tags: digital-logic, analog, latch

I want to add a circuit after comparators, so that the outputs of the comparators don't be high or low simultaneously.

i.e., if the first output goes high, the second output should be low. And if the first output goes low, the second output should be high.

[image: Circuit]

Which kind of circuits would you prefer?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to the site. [This page and links in there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270733/where-can-i-find-detailed-rules-and-guidelines) can help your questions appealing better.

Comment: You need additional details.  You don't want the outputs to be simultaneously high or low in general...but is it tolerable for a brief time?  What is that amount of time?  Everything has delays.  Also, which one takes precedence?  If A is high and B goes high, is A' forced low as B' goes high, or does A' stay high and B' stay low until A goes low?  For more questions, swap A and B, high and low, and modify the above for 3 more conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [LT1017](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1017.html#product-overview).*

> I want to add a circuit after comparators, so that the outputs of the comparators don't be high or low simultaneously.

You don't need to. The LT1017 has a weak pull-up on the output and you can parallel as many comparators as you want. If any one of then pulls low then the common output line will be pulled low.

> The output stage includes a class “B” pullup
> current source, eliminating the need for an external
> resistive pull-up and saving power. [Datasheet.]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flL2FG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. The equivalent circuit. Note that the comparators will have a strong pull-down and a week pull-up.*

Comment: I'm not convinced this answers the OP's question.

Comment: Can you offer an interpretation of the OP's question? It's not very clear.

Comment: I think the OP may be asking a question that has no answer, i.e. how to arrange things so that there are two outputs, such that at all times, exactly one of which is high, and the other is low. The problem lying in the fact that that the input may drive both comparators low, or both high. Now, it _may_ be that your solution solves what the OP _should_ have asked, but it is not clear to me that it solves what the OP _did_ ask.

Comment: I've editted my question, please check it.

Comment: Two things would help. 1. Explain what is the real problem you're trying to solve. 2. Draw a truth table for what you want. It should cover all possible combinations of the inputs and show the desired outputs for each pair. Right now the question is not any clearer.